# ListPreference's getString returns index (as string) instead of my string values in XML

Tags: java, android, enums, sharedpreferences, listpreference

OK, my general setup for using `PreferenceFragment` seems to be correct, however, I am trying to read in a value from my `SharedPreferences` on startup. That value would be mapped to an `Enum` that I created.

My first approach dealt with getting the index (as `String`) of the `string-array` (my string-array values). So I would get the Index as a string and convert it to an `Integer`. Then I would get all my `string-array` strings, and grab the one at the correct index. From there I would do an `Enum.valueOf(String)`. Volia...done.

This seemed like a lot of overhead, and I thought I could get rid of all the  `Index` middle-man stuff. So I changed all my `string-array values` from string-numbers to string that represent the `Enum` name.

**However, this is still giving me the index as a string. why?
Can I not have actual strings for my values?**

### Code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getBaseContext(), R.xml.preferences, false);

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    // Assigns enumString the value of "2", not "BUFFER". This is my issue!
    String enumString = pref.getString(
            getString(R.string.pref_search_method_key),
            Search.BUFFER.name());

    searchMethod = Search.valueOf(enumString);

}
```

### XML

```
<string-array name="search_method">
    <item>After a New Character</item>
    <item>After a Word</item>
    <item>After 3 Characters</item>
    <item>None</item>
</string-array>

<!-- Before I gave these the values 0, 1, 2, 3  -->
<string-array name="search_method_values">
    <item>CHARACTER</item>
    <item>WORD</item>
    <item>BUFFER</item>
    <item>PHRASE</item>
</string-array>
```

.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="@string/pref_header_search">

        <ListPreference
            android:key="@string/pref_search_method_key"
            android:title="@string/pref_search_method"
            android:summary="@string/pref_search_method_description"
            android:defaultValue="BUFFER"
            android:entries="@array/search_method"
            android:entryValues="@array/search_method_values" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    ...

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Comment: Did you clear the app's data or reinstalled the app to clear the older preferences ?

Comment: Ultimately, this was the issue. I knew about clearing the app data before, and did it before, but failed to do it this time. Anyway, I went back to the old way and it worked. Then it just stopped working because it had finally switched to "BUFFER". So I reimplemented my new way and cleared all the  data. All is well now, except for a few other issues I have posted on SO